# Formato de Data XML NFe

Tags: xml, vb.net, pl-sql, nfe

Estou tentando inserir uma data em uma tabela do PL-SQL da oracle.

Eu busco a data ao ler o XML de uma NFe, porém a tag  aparece desta forma `<dhEmi>2015-10-02T14:49:52-04:00</dhEmi>` fiz algumas pesquisas na internet e vi que o formato é este yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-SSSS sendo o conjunto -SSSS o fuso horário do local.

Apesar das pesquisas que fiz, não entendi como eu converto essa data diretamente no Visual Studio para um formato que o Oracle aceite, ou seja, o formato yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss.

Tentei to_date e to_char, mas ambos não funcionaram, continua retornando formato de entrada invalida.

Comment: De acordo com o manual da NFe, o formato da data é: `AAAA-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (UTC 
Universal Coordinated Time)`

Comment: Obrigado pela informação !

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com o manual da NFe, o formato da data é:
 `AAAA-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (UTC Universal Coordinated Time)`